# Difference between storing both internal and External table in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, hive

I have an internal table and External table in S3. What is the difference between having an internal table in HDFS and S3? What is the difference between internal table and External table that is stored in S3? If I drop the external table in S3, the metadata in the master node will get deleted and data will be there in S3, then how I can access the data in S3 since the metadata is deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Hive table, does not matter internal(managed) or external can have location in S3 or HDFS. There is no connection between table(managed or external) type and storage(S3, HDFS).

The difference between managed and external table is that when you delete table or partition, it's location with files also will be deleted. When you delete external table or it's partition, location will remain. Only metadata will be deleted. You can access data in S3 or HDFS location by reading files directly or by creating Hive table or partition and specifying a location. You even can create more than one tables pointing to same location, does not matter, S3 or HDFS.

See here about S3 and HDFS differences: https://www.xplenty.com/blog/2014/03/storing-apache-hadoop-data-cloud-hdfs-vs-s3/
And here: https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/31/top-5-reasons-for-choosing-s3-over-hdfs.html Though [since DEC 2020 Amazon S3 is strongly consistent](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-strong-read-after-write-consistency/).

Comment: let's assume i have a managed and external table in s3,i am using RDS for storing my metadata , i have a EC2 instance and i am running a query1 .The EC2 instance will have a master node and some core nodes say 3 core nodes.The master node should have the meta data right?.so how it will get the metadata from RDS and what will happen to the changes that i made in metadat if i lost the cluster?2.The data is stored in s3,so if i am working with managed table the data should be on any one of the core node right? then based on what parameter master node will decide which core node to assign the task

Comment: In S3 data is not stored on the cluster nodes, it is stored on NAS and can be accessed from many clusters, this is more scalable and cheap. So if you lost cluster, data will remain in S3. Metadata can be stored in RDS for example MySQL.